Ubuntu USB boot fails and drops me to initramfs
I'm trying to dual boot install from an Ubuntu live USB. I turned off Secure Boot. It gets me to the grub boot menu. Selecting Try Ubuntu fails to find the filesystem and throws an AE_NOT_FOUND error message. I tried to pass through grub with multiple settings like apci=off and several variants.
Eventually it drops me to initramfs, and I have a basic shell, but I can't fsck to fix the filesystem. I also tried to mount /dev/sda1, but it doesn't see the device.
